# Can one find the minima of a convex function efficiently?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, polynomial-time

Say I have a real valued convex function $f$ on the hypercube $[-1,1]^n$ and let $f'$ be its restriction on the discrete hypercube $\{-1,1\}^n$.

- Is there any $poly(n)$ algorithm that for any class of $f$ (and $f'$) can find the minima of it?
- Is there any relation known between the point where $f$ minimizes and the vertex where $f'$ minimizes?  Like if knowing one of them helps find the other in $poly(n)$ time?

Comment: How is your function given? Also, the minimum is not necessarily achieved at just one point: for any convex subset $S\subseteq[0,1]^n$, consider the function which maps each $x$ to its distance $d(x,S)$ from $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Minimizing a [submodular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function) can be done in [polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submodular_set_function#Submodular_Minimization).  This applies to functions on the discrete hypercube $\{-1,1\}^n$.

Comment: Well, I am starting with a convex function on $[-1,1]^n$. So either I need a solution that uses only that property or I need a method to prove that this induces a submodular function on the discrete hypercube...

Comment: @user6818, OK.  Perhaps I misinterpreted the question.  What did you mean by "for any class"?  I assumed you meant "is there a class of $f$ such that it's possible to find the minimum of $f$".  Is that not what you meant?  If not, you might want to edit to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Think of being given a convex $f$ on $[-1,1]^n$. Now what are your options? Is there something about the hypercubes $[-1,1]^n$ and $\{-1,1\}^n$ that makes this minimization on them doable in polynomial time? Is it possible that one can minimize in $[-1,1]^n$ in polynomial time and from the minima thus detected be able to get the vertex of $\{-1,1\}^n$ on which the restricted function minimizes? is there a way to show that the function restricted on $\{-1,1\}^n$ is submodular? (if so)